Set value of one column in the select result
I am trying to replace the value of one of the columns in the SELECT result to 0. Normally I can do:
SELECT
    0 AS column_to_set,
    other_col_1,
    other_col_2,
    ...
FROM tbl

However, there are lots of "other_cols" in the source table, and I wanted to avoid typing them all out.
Is there any way I can utilize SELECT * but achieve the goal of replacing the value for one specific column? The engine is AWS Athena.

I neved used amazon athena, but here a solution for Postgres, maybe it helps: https://dbfiddle.uk/490qjICE

Might help: Select all columns except one when joining two tables in AWS Athena - Stack Overflow

@JonasMetzler this is not a complete solution since it requires some "outside" manipulations. This is a solution for SQL Server for example which has an exec which as far as I remember allows executing a string as SQL query (but it was a looooong time since I've worked with SQL Server).

@GuruStron The fiddle I added in my comment shows it works on as Postgres DB. As said, I don't use Athena. Just heard from a friend it is similar to a Postgres DB and thought maybe my comment would help. That's why I added it as comment, not as an answer ;)

@JonasMetzler this will work for Athena too (with slight modifications), my point is not about that.

This is not supported in standard ANSI SQL as far as I know and this is not supported in Trino/Presto. And you can't dynamically generate AND execute query (i.e. in one query) in Trino/Presto too (see this discussion @github).
The only "easy" option is to automate this by using information_schema.columns to generate the desired query. It can be done via a separate query (i.e. you write a query which will generate the desired one) or some "outside" scripting. For example imagine we have nation table with columns nationkey, name, regionkey and comment with goal to replace comment. Then the following query:
select 'SELECT 0 AS new_comment, ' -- column to replace
         || array_join(array_agg(column_name), ', ') -- rest of the column
    || ' FROM nation' as query
from information_schema.columns 
where table_schema = 'tiny' and table_name='nation'
    AND column_name <> 'comment';

Will result in the following output:
                              query
-----------------------------------------------------------------
 SELECT 0 AS new_comment, nationkey, name, regionkey FROM nation


this is in MYSQL but maybe you can grasp some idea here:
SET @columnnames = (SELECT CONCAT("`",GROUP_CONCAT(`COLUMN_NAME` SEPARATOR "`, `"),"`")  
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS`  WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='**your_schema**' 
    AND `TABLE_NAME`='**your_table**'
    AND COLUMN_NAME != '**column_to_set**');

SET @sql = CONCAT("SELECT '**value_to_set**' as '**column_to_set**', ",@columnnames," FROM your_table");

PREPARE result FROM @sql; EXECUTE result;


Presto/Trino does not have ability to execute dynamically generated SQL. PREPARE requires "actual" script not a string.
